# Mysql database select method

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with a structure like following.

```
id          date                    ip          pack    type    set
114879  Sep 20 19:27:18             4.2.2.2     317032  flows/s 1
114880  Sep 20 19:32:22             4.2.2.2     446906  flows/s 1
114881  Sep 20 19:32:22             8.8.8.8     446906  bits/s  1
118215  Sep 20 21:07:43             4.2.2.2                     0
114879  Sep 20 21:27:18             4.2.2.2     317032  flows/s 1
114880  Sep 20 21:32:22             4.2.2.2     446906  flows/s 1
```

I want to group the result from the mysql by date ( min - max ) but this will be determined from three other columns:

- `set` = 1 - will be below the min date and the max date will be set
  form the column `set` = 0
- `ip` - will something like `id` must be unique if `type` will be one of
  "flows/s","bits/s" or "packets/s"
- `ip` - count the numbers of ip between min date and max date
- `type` - will show in function of `ip`
- if `ip` is receiving "flows/s" and "bits/s" this is will display:

.

```
DateMin            DateMax            CountIp      ip            PackMin      PackMax       type
Sep 20 19:27:18    Sep 26 23:58:13    176798       4.2.2.2                    99987         flows/s
Sep 20 19:27:20    Sep 26 23:58:13    176798       4.2.2.2                    99987         bits/s
```

How can I write a query on the described database to achieve my desired output?

Comment: So the end date should be "Sep 20 21:07:43" in this case, because set=0? When is the start date? Can you please provide a little more detail, this part is a little confusing.

Comment: The start date will be `Sep 20 19:27:18` because `set` = 1 and the end date will be `Sep 20 21:07:43` , `set` = 0

Comment: Are you setting a start date manually or is it calculated somehow? To use the date of an existing row, you will need to use a JOIN.

Comment: The all rows are generated from a log with a bash script and inserted to mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` keyword

(e.x: `SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY feild1 ORDER BY feild2 ASC` USE `DSC` instead of `ASC` if you want to result descending )

`ASC` = Ascending,

`DSC` = descending